# Make some part of the code work parallel with the main code

Tags: multithreading, perl, multiprocessing

How can i create a function that will run in a while loop without any termination parallel to my main code

```
sub somefunction{
 while(1){
   print $a+$b;
 }
}

my $a=1;
my $b=2;

somefunction(); #make it work without termination

#Main Body
while (1) {
   $c = <STDIN>;
   print $a+$b+$c;
}
```

This is just an exmaple what i want to do, The `somefunction()` should always print `$a+$b`, I've read. I've read [perl threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) but using `threads->create('somefunction', '');` did not give me any expecting result...

Comment: It wouldn't, because `$a` and `$b` are not in scope, so are null. It's printing a null string over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more of a complicated problem than you think it is. Threading will do the trick, but with any parallel processing you get some somewhat interesting potential problems.

A thread is a subroutine that runs in parallel. However, when it starts, it inherits the memory state of your program, and uses that.

In the example you list, `$a` and `$b` are not in scope for your sub, so it won't do anything. (Note - these are bad variables to use, because `sort` uses them - they therefore won't ring the alarm bells under `strict` and `warnings` if you're misusing them).

Something like this will 'work':

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

my $param_1 = 1;
my $param_2 = 2;

sub parallel_part {
    while ( 1 ) { 
        print $param_1 + $param_2, "\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
}


#Main Body

#start our thread...
my $thr = threads -> create ( \&parallel_part );


while (1) {
    my $input_value = <STDIN>;
    print $param_1 + $param_2 + $input_value,"\n";
 }

#wait for our thread to exit
#will never happen, because we've got two 'while true' loops. 
$thr -> join();
```

This is a bit of an artificial case though - the real question is 'what are you trying to accomplish?'. This'll just repeatedly print '3' over and over again, because you never change the parameters. (If you want to do this from outside your thread, you'll need to use `threads::shared`).

Comment: Note that each thread has its own `$param_1`. Changing one won't change the other.